# Jenkins downstream jobs not triggered after enabling security

Tags: security, jenkins, triggers, anonymous

I currently have two jenkins freestyle jobs setup. One is titled AutomatedBackup, and the other AutomatedBackupCleanup. Upon successful completion of the AutomatedBackup job, the AutomatedBackupCleanup job is triggered.

I have recently enabled security on my Jenkins instance, which appears to have broken the trigger between the two jobs. The console output from the AutomatedBackup job looks like so:

```
Started by user Chuck Norris
Running as Chuck Norris
Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/AutomatedBackup/workspace
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson8177383812364662730.sh
+ cp -a /var/lib/jenkins /opt/jenkinsbackups
+ cd /opt/jenkinsbackups
+ date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S
+ tar czf jenkinsBackup_20170712-153210.tar.gz jenkins/

+ rm -rf /opt/jenkinsbackups/jenkins/

+ git add --all

+ git commit -m Jenkins Automated Backup
[master 50d9f46] Jenkins Automated Backup
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 jenkinsBackup_20170712-153210.tar.gz
+ git push

To ssh://git@178.70.84.195:7999/at/jenkinsbackup.git
   cea558b..50d9f46  master -> master
Running as anonymous cannot even see AutomatedBackup for trigger from AutomatedBackupCleanup
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I'm not sure what may be causing this. It looks like the build is both started and run as my user, however the console output reports that:

```
Running as anonymous cannot even see AutomatedBackup for trigger from AutomatedBackupCleanup
```

Thanks in advance for any direction or steps that would be helpful in resolving this issue!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the root cause of this issue and would like to leave some information here for those who may stumble across this issue in the future.

The issue appears to be that the AutomatedBackupCleanup job was set in its' configuration to build only after the AutomatedBackup job completed successfully. What I had to do instead, was add a post build action to the AutomatedBackup job to trigger the build of another project (and specified the AutomatedBackupCleanup job).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a post build action, the reason is that anonymous users cannot see builds. Go to Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security, scroll down to Access Control - Authorization, then check the 'Job > Read' box for Anonymous. It should allow other jobs to be triggered.